# inst is undefined on countdown

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, countdown

I'm using this great plugins : http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

I have 3 countdown timers which are loaded with a json array. When I want to recharge them they block and this error appears:

TypeError: inst.options is undefinedjquery.countdown.js:682:1
    jQuery 4
        _generateHTML
        _updateCountdown
        _updateElems
        timerCallBack

Here my code on first load after ajax load (in success state) (regen give x seconds) :

```
var timer = [];
$.each(json.element, function (index, value) {                  
    if($.isNumeric(json.regen[i])){ 
        var timer = json.regen[i];
        var stat = json.stat[i];
        //Creating the countdown for each element
        $("#under_"+value).html('+1 in <span id="countdown_'+json.element[i]+'"></span>');
        //initialize countdown and loop it at the end.
        $('#countdown_'+json.element[i]).countdown({until: timer, compact: true, format: 'MS', onExpiry: function() {
            getattribute(stat);
            }
        });
    };
    i++;
});
```

When i click on button to refresh those countdown the error appear...
How can i fix it ?

Here the codepen : https://codepen.io/Logobi/pen/KKdmNby

Thx

Comment: Can you provide a codepen or a snippet that will allow us to test this?

Comment: Here my friend : https://codepen.io/Logobi/pen/KKdmNby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seem OK, i have to check countdown before reinitialize it. If countdown isn't over, i let it down and if its over, i reload getattribute.

```
let oCountdown = $('#countdown_'+[i]+'_'+element[i]);
  if(oCountdown.length>0){
    oCountdown.countdown('option', "until", timer);
  }else{
    $("#under_"+elemval).html('+1 in <span id="countdown_'+[i]+'_'+element[i]+'"></span>');
    $('#countdown_'+[i]+'_'+element[i]).countdown(
      {
        until: timer,
        format: 'MS',
        compact: true,   
        onExpiry:function() {
          getattribute();
        }
      }
    );// format ii:ss
  }
```

Here the solution in codepen :
https://codepen.io/Zonecss/pen/jObmdBM